# How to keep first and last values for each date in list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a nested list that has a structure like this:

```
longlist = [["Bob", "2019-12-12 19:03"], ["Joe", "2019-12-12 19:04"], 
["Sally", "2019-12-12 21:07"], ["Jane", "2019-12-13 2:02"], 
["Jose", "2019-12-13 3:04"], ["Ahmed", "2019-12-13 3:06"], 
["Xi", "2019-12-13 7:43"]]
```

My goal is to keep only the first and last item from `longlist` for **each date**. Using the above nested list, the output I desire is:

```
newlist = [["Bob", "2019-12-12 19:03"], ["Sally", "2019-12-12 21:07"], 
["Jane", "2019-12-13 2:02"], ["Xi", "2019-12-13 7:43"]]
```

I searched throughout SO and online, but couldn't find what I was looking for. Does anyone know how this is possible?

Comment: what have you tried so far? are first and last regarding time, or location in list?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Hi Tomerikoo, thanks for your reply. I'm relatively new to programming so I wasn't sure how to do it. I looked at examples online, but none do what I'm searching for. I also tried experimenting by first converting the second item in every list/item into EPOCH and manipulating it there, but it didn't work and I ended up being more confused than I started, which is why I came here.

Comment: What should happen if there's an item with unique date? It should be added once, twice or discarded?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Hi Andrej, there will be no items with a unique date. All dates have at least 10 items.

Comment: @F16Falcon i added a pure pandas solution as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)) and group elements by date string (after splitting it).

For example:

```
from itertools import groupby

longlist = [["Bob", "2019-12-12 19:03"], ["Joe", "2019-12-12 19:04"],
            ["Sally", "2019-12-12 21:07"], ["Jane", "2019-12-13 2:02"],
            ["Jose", "2019-12-13 3:04"], ["Ahmed", "2019-12-13 3:06"],
            ["Xi", "2019-12-13 7:43"]]

out = []
for _, g in groupby(longlist, lambda k: k[1].split()[0]):
    first, *_, last = g
    out.extend([first, last])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['Bob', '2019-12-12 19:03'],
 ['Sally', '2019-12-12 21:07'],
 ['Jane', '2019-12-13 2:02'],
 ['Xi', '2019-12-13 7:43']]
```

Note: Based on your comment, I didn't check for unique date (as you stated, *All dates have at least 10 items.*)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure pandas solution:

```
df5 = pd.DataFrame(longlist)
df5['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df5[1]) 

list(map(list,list(df5.groupby(df5['datetime'].dt.day).agg('first').append(df5.groupby(df5['datetime'].dt.day).agg('last')).drop(columns='datetime').set_index(0).to_dict()[1].items())))

[['Bob', '2019-12-12 19:03'],
 ['Jane', '2019-12-13 2:02'],
 ['Sally', '2019-12-12 21:07'],
 ['Xi', '2019-12-13 7:43']]
```